# BSD netcat how to terminate after sending command?

Tags: scripting, echo, netcat, bsd

```
echo "test" | nc -N -U example.soc
```

How can I have this terminate once it has successfully sent the message over?

According to the man page:

> There should now be a connection between the ports. Anything typed at
>   the second console will be concatenated to the first, and vice-versa.
>   After the connection has been set up, nc does not really care which
>   side is being used as a ‘server’ and which side is being used as a
>   ‘client’. The connection may be terminated using an EOF (‘^D’).

Can I send this as a character via echo?

---

Okay so it seems it also relies on the host to be sending something (some signal to close the connection?) before the command terminates.

Comment: You have a listening side as well, don't you? What does that look like? When I'm testing this on OpenBSD, exactly like you have shown, and with another instance doing `nc -N -U -l example.soc` in the same directory, both sides terminate a soon as the message has been sent.

Comment: Yes - a custom program that is listening on the socket. It seems it is responsible for closing the connection - after which the client `nc` will successfully terminate.

Comment: that will terminate as soon as `echo test` has terminated, _if_ you tell `nc` to exit immediately after EOF on its stdin with `-q0`: `echo test | nc -q0 ...`. As to "sending EOF", this has been treaded to death -- there's nothing to send: as soon as `echo test | ...` has terminated, a read on the right side of the pipeline will get a count of 0, which _is_ EOF.

Comment: `-q` is not part of bsd netcat it seems? `invalid option -- 'q'`

Comment: Yes, when the message has been sent, the ball is on the listener's side.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that `-q` was a generally implemented flag. If you're on OpenBSD, you can use the `-W recvlimit` flag ("terminate after receiving recvlimit packets"): `echo test | nc -NUW1 /path/to/sock` (no, there's no general "BSD netcat", please specify the _exact_ operating system and version).

Comment: If that doesn't work either, you'll have to fix the "custom program" -- I suppose that it's not properly closing the accepted socket fd after finishing its work with it, or after passing it to a forked child.